# How do I enable Multisite on WP 3.7.1?

Tags: multisite, wp-config

(Using Wordpress 3.7.1) Adding the string `define(‘WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE’, true);` to my `wp-config.php` file isn't giving me the 'Network' choice in the Tools menu, even after multiple logouts and waiting a bit.

I didn't anticipate ever needing this feature, but...well..ya know.

Can anyone help me out with this? I can't seem to find anything helpful. There are lots of tutorials, but they all seem to pretty much say the same thing.

Thx!
-C

Comment: If you have followed codex the right way, then you should be able to see the options but if you dont, then let us know what have you done to debug it

Comment: Is this a new or existing WP that you have upgraded?

Comment: There is a specific place to put the above code to make it work. Check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_2:_Allow_Multisite So have you placed it correctly?

Comment: If you have no syntax error, also in the quation marks`? `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE' , true );`

Comment: Oddly enough, I gave it another crack this AM with a different FTP client this AM (WinSCP if you're interested) and was able to get the 'Network' option to appear in my Tools menu.

Comment: There was a question earlier as to whether this was an existing site or not. The site is roughly 2 years old, and we're trying to build some new functionality into it. The goal is to add in BuddyPress and allow users to create blogs/profiles...etc. So, we need the multisite function (at least according to their documentation).

Comment: Reminder: This is WP 3.7.1 - When I tried to go to the "Network" option in the Tools menu I received the following warning: "Please deactivate your plugins before enabling the Network feature". 

The only thing that I have found online that is marked as a "solution" is this: "It wasn't a mu-plugins plugin, but a "drop-in" (Drop-ins) plugin (advanced-cache.php), that was preventing reinstall/install of WPMS."

Answer (score 0):

This article explains very graphically http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/creating-a-network-to-enable-wordpress-multisite/

Comment: Actually, that was one of the first ones that I came across and attempted to use. As I mentioned before, when I add the strip of code that is listed, I do not get the "Network" option listed under the "Tools" menu. I assume it's because I am using a later version of WP? 

Any ideas? There is just no change at all when I make the addition to the wp-config file. Nothing good or bad...it seems to ignore it completely. 

Thanks for taking the time to comment. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently set up a Wordpress Multisite Network on 3.7.1 and it went without bigger problems. I followed [this tutorial](http://kidvolt.com/multiple-domains-on-wordpress). However, what I did, and what is not mentioned I think, is that I added that line to wp-config.php before I began the installation process.

It should be relatively easy to create a new WP installation (initially setting it up as a network), and then migrating your current website into one of the blogs (=sites, under WP Network).